# VisualVM will not connect to remote, hangs at Preferences > Network

Tags: macos, visualvm

VisualVM connects to a local karaf instance without any problems but will not make a remote connection. Others on my team have this remote connection working.

Also VisualVM hangs when I go to VisualVM > Preferences ... > Network

This leads me to believe it may be some kind of permission/firewall problem.
I am on OSX 11.4 Big Sur, VisualVM is version 2.0.7.

The firewall log at /private/var/log/appfirewall.log is empty because apparently [it only logs user-defined rules.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/294553/logging-macbook-firewall-is-empty?rq=1)

I don't know if VisualVM has any logs, have not found them yet.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the connection failed because there was a hard to spot typo in the remote url.
When i fixed the typo, the connection became available.
Found this out using jconsole which comes standard with jdk, and does give you an error when the connection url is faulty.

tl;dr Try a different tool before trying to troubleshoot with VisualVM.

Regarding troubleshooting with VisualVM:

1. VisualVM hangs on VisualVM > Preferences ... > Network regardless.
2. The connection problems do not show up in the log.

Logging for VirtualVM is enabled by setting the log properties the `/Applications/VisualVM.app/Contents/Resources/visualvm/etc/visualvm.conf` file.
You do this by adding `J-Djava.util.logging.config.file=<log.properties>` to the list in `visualvm_default_options`.

In your log.properties file you define the log-file and log-level, as usual:

```
handlers = java.util.logging.FileHandler
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern   = ~/visualvm.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level   = INFO
```